# Key Value pair to NoSQL database

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to load a dataframe to NoSQL. Input is a CSV format file with data as

I/P :

```
+--------+------+---+---+---+---+----+----+
|DATE    |VAL|100|200|300|400|101 |201 |
+--------+------+---+---+---+---+----+----+
|20200701|A  |1  |2  |3  |4  |1.1 |2.1 |
|20201001|B  |10 |20 |30 |40 |10.1|20.1|
+--------+------+---+---+---+---+----+----+
```

val_1=[100,200,300,400]

Need to dump columns in val1 to a json struct "val_1" and remaining columns in "val_2". Desired output

O/P:

```
{
"DATE": "20200701",
"VAL": "A",
"val_1": {
"100":"1",
"200":"2",
"300":"3",
"400":"4"
},
"val_2": {
"101":"1.1",
"201":"2.1"
},
{
"DATE": "20201001",
"VAL": "B",
"val_1": {
"100":"10",
"200":"20",
"300":"30",
"400":"40"
},
"val_2": {
"101":"10.1",
"201":"20.1"
}
```

Comment: for every json struct in O/P , api call will be made to insert the data in NO SQL.

Comment: What is the NO SQL db you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You probably have a better way to perform that task with an [already existing connector](https://github.com/audienceproject/spark-dynamodb) but still, here is the solution to your current post :

```py
df.withColumn("val_1", F.struct(["100", "200", "300", "400"])).withColumn(
    "val_2", F.struct(["101", "201",])
).select("DATE", "VAL", "val_1", "val_2").toJSON().collect()

['{"DATE":"20200701","VAL":"A","val_1":{"100":1,"200":2,"300":3,"400":4},"val_2":{"101":1.1,"201":2.1}}',
 '{"DATE":"20201001","VAL":"B","val_1":{"100":10,"200":20,"300":30,"400":40},"val_2":{"101":10.1,"201":20.1}}']
```